# How to target a specific triangle and it neighbor in an IcosahedronGeometry

Tags: three.js

I would like to color each triangle of the following Icosahedron based on a value associated to the triangle and the value of it neighbors.
https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/geometries/IcosahedronGeometry

But I am having trouble understanding how to target a specific triangle and it neighbors in order to apply the color.

Comment: I don’t understand your question. How are you targeting the triangle? Let’s see what you’ve tried, and what you’re trying to achieve.

Comment: @Marquizzo here is an example of code https://jsfiddle.net/46bvwuf2/5/

Comment: Here is something close to what I need, but it's using click and interection to get a face. I don't know how to access a face without a click https://jsfiddle.net/fg4y3wLa/